# Azure Data Factory UI - Author and Monitor does not load

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Clicking on Author and Monitor for Azure Data Factory V2 does not load the UI. It keeps saying Loading..... and nothing happens.

I tried clearing browser cache, history.
Tried different browsers.
Tried directly logging into ADF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,please see this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal#create-a-data-factory): Currently, Data Factory UI is supported only in Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome web browsers.

I often experience this issue but not always.The azure data factory UI keep loading or  keep asking me to re-enter my account information. I fixed it by using `incognito` mode in the browser.

You could find many clues from this [MSDN case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26dd2244-efa2-4225-a32f-2f68d3a60139/data-factory-ui-is-not-loading?forum=AzureDataFactory).

---

Updates at 30.DEC.2019:

The UI started working after couple of days without any changes.

Comment: Tried all these options , still no luck. Even re-installed chrome.

Comment: @Dataman you could contact with adf official team and ask for help.Any progress,you could post here.

Comment: A bit late responding.... not sure what changed it started working after couple of days.

Comment: @Dataman Good news. I updated my answer, you could accept it to end this case.Thank you!